# How to link to other php file in wordpress theme folder?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, dynamic-linking

I've added new template in wordpress's theme folder and a page that uses that template. In my php script there is a button that has onClick function:

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="parent.location='MYQUIZTABLE.php'" VALUE="SEND">
```

The button (after pressed) should link to other php script (called MYQUIZTABLE.php), but *"404 not found"* is shown on localhost. Where should i put second php script? Or how can i link to that script in my code?

Comment: is 'MYQUIZTABLE.php' in the same folder as your template file? That's where it should be.

Comment: Why do you need to redirect to a PHP file in wordpress? It is not a proper approach. Write your functionalities as functions in functions.php and initiate this function when needed

Answer (score 1):

Include full url from MYQUIZTABLE.php file.
You can use [get_template_directory();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) or [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) for this.

Comment: That is correct suggestion. Something like: `<?php $uriToFile = get_template_directory_uri() . "/MYQUIZTABLE.php"; ?>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="parent.location='<?php echo $uriToFile; ?>'" VALUE="SEND">` works nice.